# apt-get not recognizing downloaded archives

Tags: installation, apt, software-center, deb, archive

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. I previously had Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 and had all the archives in the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` stored to a removable disk. After installing 13.10 I copied all my archives to the above mentioned path. When I run `apt-get install` it tries to fetch the archives

[image]

although I have the archives.

[image]

Also if instead of `apt-get install` if I try to install individual .deb files using `dpkg -i` everything runs fine. These are the permissions of files:

[image]

How do I fix this. Previously copying archives like this worked fine and downloading duplicates the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 and Ubuntu 13.10 have different versions of the Gimp and other packages. The versions the system knows about, as listed in its APT sources, are not the same ones you have in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. So it tries downloading the ones it needs.

Using `apt-cache policy` (e.g., "`apt-cache policy gimp`") can often shed light on this sort of issue. Or go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and enter a package name, to see which package versions are in which versions of the OS.

Comment: Thanks I found that there is slight version chankge in all the packages. I'll have to download all the packages again.